# Sorting the User input in Java

Tags: java, string, sorting, java.util.scanner

I am beginner in Java. I need help to proceed my code. Thanks in advance.

Question: Given a unsorted list of 5 athletes nominated for the coaching class, provide a way for the coach  to search for the athlete name and provide grades. Finally print the list of athletes’ names with their grade in the sorted order of their names. Search for the athlete with highest grade.

---

```
package student;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Atheletes {
    String name;
    static String  grade,grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of athelete1 and grade");
        grade1 = in.nextLine();
        Scanner ino = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of athelete2 and grade");
        grade2 = ino.nextLine();
        Scanner ine = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of athelete3and grade");
        grade3 = ine.nextLine();
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of athelete4 and grade");
        grade4 = inp.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  What is happening instead?

Comment: You will need to at least try and show us how far you got. This is not a site to request code.

Comment: i want to print this in sorted order of the names as well as  to search using names

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach. Look into HashMap s and sorting.

Comment: Before you go running to a HashMap or any other collection @sweetyshines, Are you required to code the search algorithm by hand, or are you allowed to use one of the built-in searches.  And are you required to build your own storage algorithm? This is critical.

Comment: Please create only one `Scanner` instance and reuse it. No need to create additional instances.

Comment: i am allowed to use binary search algorithm

Comment: ok will remove other scanner instances Tom

Comment: @sweetyshines, So you have to implement the search algorithm itself then?  And are you allowed to use existing collections or not?  These are all things that a junior programming class might require you make by hand.

Comment: @sweetyshines Yeah I forgot to ask. Because I didn't realize it was HW at first. What are you allowed to use? If you have no restrictions I suggest using an HashMap, if you are restricted to a List (ArrayList) things are a bit different. Can you use Collections.sort()?

Comment: i don't know anything about collections and all.if i sort this program in alphabetical order of names means thats well and good first..

Comment: no i cannot use collections.sort()

Comment: how to sort all the user inputs?

Comment: Can you use arrays and for loops?

Comment: yes i can use arrays and for loops @Angelo Alvisi

Comment: I guess inner classes are also out of discussion... or parametered constructors... ugh... I'll post something.

Comment: @sweetyshines, please see my updated answer with bubble sorting approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have simplified your code and added comments as necessary.

```
    // number of Athletes you want
    Athlete[] eAthlete = new Athlete[5];
    // Name of each athlete
    String[] names = { "ss", "aa", "bb", "cc", "xx" };

    // On each iteration, the name of the Athlete
    // and his/her grade is set,

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < eAthlete.length; i++) {
        eAthlete[i] = new Athlete();
        eAthlete[i].setName(names[i]);
        System.out.println("Please enter Grade for: "
                + eAthlete[i].getName());
        eAthlete[i].setGrade(in.nextLine());
    }

    in.close();

    // Print all athletes with their grades,
    System.out.println("Before Sorting");
    for (Athlete s : eAthlete) {
        System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getGrade());
    }
```

At this point, the grades and names are assigned to each athlete,

**Output**

```
Before Sorting
ss 123
aa 65465
bb 4654
cc .0231
xx 23123
```

Now we need to sort these Athletes based on their names.

We could have designed our own `Comparator` but since, you are not allowed to use `Collections.sort`, we would use rather poor approach i.e bubble sorting,

```
 String tempStr;
 for (int t=0; t<eAthlete.length-1; t++)
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < eAthlete.length - t -1; i++)
        {
            if(eAthlete[i+1].getName().compareTo(eAthlete[i].getName())<0)
            {
                tempStr = eAthlete[i].getName();
                eAthlete[i].setName(eAthlete[i+1].getName());
                eAthlete[i+1].setName(tempStr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Printing the sorted athletes with their grades,

```
System.out.println("After Sorting");
         for (Athelete s : eAthelete){
             System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getGrade());
         }
```

**Output:**

```
After Sorting

aa 65465
bb 4654
cc .0231
ss 123
xx 23123
```

observe the names in above output.

here is your `Athlete` class,

```
class Athlete {

    private String name;
    private String grade;


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGrade(String gr) {
        grade = gr;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Here is the complete code,**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Athlete[] eAthlete = new Athlete[5];
        String[] names = { "ss", "aa", "bb", "cc", "xx" };

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < eAthlete.length; i++) {
            eAthlete[i] = new Athlete();
            eAthlete[i].setName(names[i]);
            System.out.println("Please enter Grade for: "
                    + eAthlete[i].getName());
            eAthlete[i].setGrade(in.nextLine());
        }

        in.close();

        // Print all athletes with their grades,
        System.out.println("Before Sorting");
        for (Athlete s : eAthlete) {
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getGrade());
        }

        String tempStr;

        for (int t = 0; t < eAthlete.length - 1; t++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < eAthlete.length - t - 1; i++) {
                if (eAthlete[i + 1].getName().compareTo(eAthlete[i].getName()) < 0) {
                    tempStr = eAthlete[i].getName();
                    eAthlete[i].setName(eAthlete[i + 1].getName());
                    eAthlete[i + 1].setName(tempStr);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("After Sorting");
        for (Athlete s : eAthlete) {
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " " + s.getGrade());
        }
    }
}

class Athlete {

    private String name;
    private String grade;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGrade(String gr) {
        grade = gr;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: First, she can't use an Athlete class.

Second NEVER take a O(n^2) approach when you can take a O(n) approach that amounts to the same amount of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Athletes {

private String name;
private String grade;

public Athletes(String name, String grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Athletes [name=" + name + ", grade=" + grade + "]";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Athletes> lijst = new ArrayList<Athletes>();
    lijst.add(new Athletes("bbb", "Grade1"));
    lijst.add(new Athletes("ccc", "Grade2"));
    lijst.add(new Athletes("aaa", "Grade3"));
    lijst.add(new Athletes("ddd", "Grade4"));
    Collections.sort(lijst, new Comparator<Athletes>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Athletes o1, Athletes o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });

    for (Athletes athletes : lijst) {
        System.out.println(athletes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Rest of the code or changing the code for your homework is up to you ;-)

Comment: She said she cannot use Collections.sort() this answer is moot.

Comment: Warning about this answer: Formatting is bad, naming conventions are wrong and it is not using best practices.

Comment: @Angelo Alvisi, please stop criticizing every answer with silly reasons.

Comment: @Joe Tell me, what is silly about saying that an answer doesn't respect coding conventions?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi: its just auto generated code in Eclipse, formatting is also from Eclipse so I don't now what is wrong with this?

Comment: The indentations are wrong and the naming conventions are not respected. The class name Athletes should be changed, so should list. Calling long functions inside of main is also frowned upon.

Answer (score -1):

You may write your own comparator Class to sort the Athelete on basis of their names

```
public class AtheleteComparator implements Comparator
{
         @override
         public int compare(Atheletes first,Atheletes second)
       {
            return first.name.compareTo(second.name);
       }
}
```

Then simply use

```
Collections.sort(List<Athelete>list,Your own Comparator's object)
```

To find out athelete with highest grade write another comparator which compares **grades**

then use

```
Collections.sort(arrayList,Comparator); // Sort the arraylist
arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1); //gets the last item, largest for an ascending sort
```

Comment: She can't use Collections.sort() This has been explicitly stated. Don't hijack other answers please.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi , In post this restrictions is not provided anywhere , I just read all  comments then able to know that . So Stop putting allegations !!

Comment: Even if,  you posted the exact same answer as someone else.

Answer (score -4):

Ok, since you can use arrays and for loops but not collections:

```
public class Sorter(){

    private int[] grades = {7, 6, 4, 10, 8};
    private String[] names = {"John", "Erik", "Bob", "Frank", "Judy"};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Sorter();
    }

    public Sorter(){
        int[] tempGrades = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        String[] tempNames = {"", "", "", "", ""};
        for (int x = 0; x < tempGrades.length; x++) {
            if (grades[x] < tempGrades[1]) {
                tempGrades[0] = grades[x];
                tempNames[0] = names[x];
            } else if (grades[x] < tempGrades[2]) {
                tempGrades[0] = tempGrades[1];
                tempGrades[1] = grades[x];
                tempNames[0] = tempNames[1];
                tempNames[1] = names[x];
            } else if (grades[x] < tempGrades[3]) {
                tempGrades[0] = tempGrades[1];
                tempGrades[1] = tempGrades[2];
                tempGrades[2] = grades[x];
                tempNames[0] = tempNames[1];
                tempNames[1] = tempNames[2];
                tempNames[2] = names[x];
            } else if (grades[x] < tempGrades[4]) {
                tempGrades[0] = tempGrades[1];
                tempGrades[1] = tempGrades[2];
                tempGrades[2] = tempGrades[3];
                tempGrades[3] = grades[x];
                tempNames[0] = tempNames[1];
                tempNames[1] = tempNames[2];
                tempNames[2] = tempNames[3];
                tempNames[3] = names[x];
            } else {
                tempGrades[0] = tempGrades[1];
                tempGrades[1] = tempGrades[2];
                tempGrades[2] = tempGrades[3];
                tempGrades[3] = tempGrades[4];
                tempGrades[4] = grades[x];
                tempNames[0] = tempNames[1];
                tempNames[1] = tempNames[2];
                tempNames[2] = tempNames[3];
                tempNames[3] = tempNames[4];
                tempNames[4] = names[x];
            }
        }
        grades = tempGrades;
        names = tempNames;
        for (int x = 0; x < grades.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(tempNames[x] + " " + tempGrades[x]);
        }
    } 
}
```

just for the future:

you can use an `ArrayList<Athlete>` where Athlete is a class that accepts `(String name, int grade)` as constructor paramaters and sorts athletes by grade by implementing its own comparator or you can use a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>` that sorts values by `Key<Integer>`.

Note: Class names with plural like Athletes are best used for Singleton classes that only implement static methods and variables. Always name classes by function (in this case sorting), AthleteSorter is also viable.

Comment: I would not recommend using this approach, since OP is allowed to use loops, why did't you use Bubble Sorting instead ?

Comment: Because bubble sorting is O(n^2) while Insertion Order is O(n).

Comment: Actually not O(n) but still much faster.

Comment: When you answer a question on Stack Overflow, you're teaching somebody something.  In this particular case, you're teaching a beginner something about coding.  Do you really want to teach someone a coding style that involves multiple code repetition?  Do you want to exhibit code that can't be extended in any way; for example, if there are a different number of athletes?  This isn't an answer that I would recommend that the OP try to learn anything from.

Comment: @DavidWallace Don't think I do not agree with you, but with the restrictions posed to the exercise by the teacher this was the most reasonable way I found to do what was asked. If you want to blame someone blame teachers that try to teach terrible coding practices. I'm not sure why OP said they couldn't use Collections.sort()  and accepted an answer that involves using it. I simply adapted to what was said in comments.